# How to split list into nested lists with the same first value?

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have python list (example):

```
mylist = ["AA - AA", "qwerty", "123456789", "nvidia", "fan", "8765", "AA - AA", "group", "bread", "plate", "knife", "AA - AA", "123123123", "laptop", "666"]
```

(My real list contains for about 2000 elements, what you see above is just a short example.)

I need to split that list into:

```
newlist = [["AA - AA", "qwerty", "123456789", "nvidia", "fan", "8765"], ["AA - AA", "group", "bread", "plate", "knife"], ["AA - AA", "123123123", "laptop", "666"]]
```

As you can see, each nested list has a different number of elements and the same first element "AA - AA".

How can I split a list into nested lists, so that it has the first element "AA - AA" and the last element (the element before the next "AA - AA")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the first element in *mylist* is 'AA - AA' then:

```
mylist = ["AA - AA", "qwerty", "123456789", "nvidia", "fan", "8765", "AA - AA", "group", "bread", "plate", "knife", "AA - AA", "123123123", "laptop", "666"]

result = []

for e in mylist:
    if e == 'AA - AA':
        result.append([e])
    else:
        result[-1].append(e)

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[['AA - AA', 'qwerty', '123456789', 'nvidia', 'fan', '8765'], ['AA - AA', 'group', 'bread', 'plate', 'knife'], ['AA - AA', '123123123', 'laptop', '666']]
```

**Note:**

There's certainly no need for itertools, numpy or temporary/intermediate variables for something so trivial

Answer (score 1):

python has build in method, `groupby` for this.

```py
mylist = ["AA - AA", "qwerty", "123456789", "nvidia", "fan", "8765", "AA - AA", "group", "bread", "plate", "knife", "AA - AA", "123123123", "laptop", "666"]

from itertools import groupby
x = (list(g) for _, g in groupby(mylist, key='AA - AA'.__eq__))
[i+j for i, j in zip(x, x)]

# OUPUT is:
# [['AA - AA', 'qwerty', '123456789', 'nvidia', 'fan', '8765'], ['AA - AA', 'group', 'bread', 'plate', 'knife'], ['AA - AA', '123123123', 'laptop', '666']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import numpy as np

mylist, lst = ["AA - AA", "qwerty", "123456789", "nvidia", "fan", "8765", "AA - AA", "group", "bread", "plate", "knife", "AA - AA", "123123123", "laptop", "666"], []
where = np.where(np.array(mylist + ["AA - AA"]) == "AA - AA")[0]
for i in range(len(where)-1):   lst.append(mylist[where[i]:where[i+1]-1])
print(lst)
```

Result:

```
[['AA - AA', 'qwerty', '123456789', 'nvidia', 'fan'],
 ['AA - AA', 'group', 'bread', 'plate'],
 ['AA - AA', '123123123', 'laptop']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to present a third one-line solution:

```
[mylist[idx:idx1] for idx, idx1 in zip([i for i,item in enumerate(mylist) if item=='AA - AA'][:-1],[i for i,item in enumerate(mylist) if item=='AA - AA'][1:])]
```

Explanation:

```
[i for i,item in enumerate(mylist) if item=='AA - AA']
```

returns all the index positions of your `'AA - AA'` key.
Since we want to extract the values of `mylist` between to adjacent occurences of the key I have created one list that is shifted by one using the `[1:]` Thus, no `Index ot of range` errors.
*Maybe there is a more elegant solution for this problem*

The last step is to iterate over both lists in parallel and building the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = ["AA - AA", "qwerty", "123456789", "nvidia", "fan", "8765", "AA - AA", "group", "bread", "plate", "knife", "AA - AA", "123123123", "laptop", "666"]

ranges = [i for i, j in enumerate(mylist) if j == 'AA - AA'] + [len(mylist)]
output = [[mylist[ranges[x]:ranges[x+1]]] for x in range(len(ranges)-1)]
```

Output:

```
[[['AA - AA', 'qwerty', '123456789', 'nvidia', 'fan', '8765']], [['AA - AA', 'group', 'bread', 'plate', 'knife']], [['AA - AA', '123123123', 'laptop', '666']]]
```